# ng-grid pinned columns overlapping

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I have created a view with ng-Grid.
i pin the first 3 columns shown below. The 4th column (unpinned) when scrolled, shows up under the pinned headers.
Not sure if this is a z-index issue somewhere.
(i have given the grid a custom header height in options.)
[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have given background color to cell and issue resolved but strange to see that after giving this my popover text is cutting while pinned column have only z-index:1 and popover have 1000

```
.ngCell {
    border-right: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
    background-color: #fff;
```